# Android textview and edit text data passing

Tags: android

I want to pass the contents to the text view from the edit text by using button click and also show notification that Notice posted. How to do that?? I Am new to android. Please help, if possible give a code to do the same. Please post the java code if possible. Thank You..!!

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="RECENT NOTICES"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0612"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/noticeText"
        android:hint="Post Notice"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/sndnoticeBut"
        android:src="@drawable/send1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/noticeText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/sndnoticeBut"
    android:src="@drawable/send1"
    android:background="@null"
    <!-- Add the onClick -->
    android:onClick="sendToTV"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Do the following in the Activity containing the layout

```
public void sendToTV(){
    String myText = null;

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noticeText);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    myText = et.getText.toString();
    tv.setText(myText);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir..!!

Comment: Hello.. I want to show all the messages in recycler view, Like a chat app, but it should appear only on one side, two sided layout is not required. Can you please provide me with a suitable xml and java code for the same. It would be very helpful. THANK YOU..!!

Comment: Rate up the answer then

Comment: Yes did.. Please Help.!

Comment: Sir can you please help me put a recyclerview for  the same?? So that the text remains in the text view even after closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

On your button click your_textview.setText(your_edittext.getText().toString());
For local notification http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html